# Java EE - Singleton EJB with Concurrent Access to Synchronized Method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an EJB as below. This has been created solely for test purposes - I'm "sleeping" the thread as I want to simulate the case where the query is scheduled again before the synchronized method has finished executing.

The observed behaviour is as expected - but is this the correct way to poll the database for, for example, rows that have been inserted so that some processing can be performed, before they are updated? I want the method to be synchronized as I don't want another call to modify the database state while processing those from a previous method call

```
@Singleton
public class MyResource {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MyMonitor")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Schedule(second="*", minute="*", hour="*")
    public synchronized void checkDb() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        List<ReferenceNames> l = 
            em.createQuery("from Clients cs", Clients.class).getResultList();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(l.size());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not implement a single point of database access yourself, just to make sure, that records are not changed during an update. For that, you want to use database locking. In Java EE / JPA 2.0 you have several locking modes at hand, check out for example [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java) or [this wikibook article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking). Concerning the other components trying to write during the locking, you have to react to the lock exception and implement some sort of retry mechanism.